# Отправлять "typing" в Телеграм боте

Tags: telegram-bot

Пишу телеграм бота. 
Кто-нибудь знает, как сделать задержку между сообщениями?
Чтобы не сразу отправлялись все сообщения, а с какой-то задержкой. 
В идеале, если будет писаться, допустим "typing" между отправкой.

Нашел вот [это](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendchataction), но там нельзя задать время отправки.

Answer (score 2):

```
sleep(5)
```

Все оказалось элементарно. Просто даем серверу немного поспать.